# How to get the file based on the name given the path

Tags: python, image, image-processing, text

Below is the format of text file that I have. The third and forth column is the file name without the extension of (.jpg) and the first column is the path to these files. I want to go to these path and get the image files (for example for the first line I want to get images from 000574 to 000605) and copy them in to a destination as the user input (preferred). How I can do this using python?

```
Sbj47/Scn/Clr/rgb7 22 000574 000605
Sbj47/Scn/Clr/rgb7 61 000633 000660
Sbj31/Scn6/Clr/rgb5 10 000789 000829
Sbj31/Scn6/Clr/rgb5 21 000871 000903
...
```

I have tried the below code and I failed:

```
f= open("try.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
line_parts = lines.split()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to move files or copy files? How is the destination described? As an argument, or user input? hints: You can read a file with `open('your_file.txt') as f`, but use the `with` context manager. You can read lines with `lines = f.readlines()`. You can split each line using `line_parts = line.split()`. You can take the 3rd and 4th arguments with `line_parts[3]` and `line_parts[4]`...

Comment: in `lines` you have list so you have to use `for`-loop to work with every item separatelly.

Answer (score 0):

Standard rule: If you have list then you have to use `for`-loop to work with every element separatelly.

```
destination = input("Destination: ")

os.makedirs(destination, exist_ok=True)  # create folder if doesn't exist

f = open("try.txt")
lines = f.readlines()

for item in lines:
    line_parts = item.strip().split()
    path = line_parts[0]
    start = int(line_parts[2])
    end =  int(line_parts[3])
    for number in range(star, end+1):
        old_path = os.path.join(path, '{:06}.jpg'.format(number))
        new_path = os.path.join(destination, '{:06}.jpg'.format(number))
        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
```

You can also get lines diretly from `f` without `readlines()` and use `with`.

```
with open("try.txt") as f:
    for item in f:
        # rest
```

---

**BTW:** `numpy.array` and `pandas.DataFrame` can work with every element without using `for`-loop. But for this job you don't need them.

Comment: thanks @furas. I tried your code and I got this error:`  File "try_1st.py", line 14
    old_path = os.path.join(path, f'{number}.jpg')
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: if you use older Python then you need `'{}.jpg'.format(number)`

Comment: I don't know why but the images are in the path as mentioned in the text file

Comment: small correction because `number` is integer variable so it doesn't have zeros at the beginning and it needs `{:06}` when it is converted to string `'{:06}.jpg'.format(number)` to put zeros in filename.

Comment: I am running this python code in bash and when it is asking me for `Destination` I give the path to the directory that I want like`path/to/myfavorite` and it is giving me name `path` is not defined

Comment: show full message - there should be info in which line is problem.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try_1st.py", line 2, in <module>
    destination = input("Destination: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 's' is not defined`    `s` is part of path I am giving! like `s/...`     And yes I have the `path = line_parts[0]` in my code!

Comment: it seems you use Python2. Then you have to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Comment: BTW: you should start using Python 3 - see [Python 2 countdown](https://pythonclock.org/)

Comment: Something is still wrong with this code, I am getting the error below: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 15, in <module>
    os.rename(old_path, new_path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Sbj47/Scn/Clr/rgb7/000574.jpg' -> 'New/path/000574.jpg'` even though the files and directories are present!

Comment: it is relative path. it search it in folder in which you run code. If source/destination folder is in different folder then it will not find them.  Use absolute path (full path) which starts with `/`. The same can be with source and destionation folder.

Comment: BTW: use `print( os.getcwd() )` to see in which folder it runs code. And `print( os.listdir(".") )` to see if folder `Sbj47` exists in this place. The same with `new/path` folder. I added `os.makedirs(destination)` in code to create destination folder.

Comment: I used the full path and it didn't work as well. The weird thing is, I am getting the copied image files in the new directory but still this error persists.

Comment: are you get EXACTLY the same error when you use full path ? If not then you have different problem and you should create new question on new page. And it means that your current problem was resolved.

Comment: Yes exact same error but this time no image in the new directory!

Comment: but you said you get copied images in new directory.

Comment: With the relative path not with the full path!

Comment: so it copy images with full path but you still get the same error ? If different error then you have another problem in different place. If you still have the same problem with relative path then you still have wrong path and you have to create correct path - but I can't help because I don't know in which folder you have file and in which folder code is running. You have `os.getcwd()` to check in which folder it runs code and in this folder it will use relative pathes - like `os.getcwd() + "/ " + path`

Comment: It did NOT copy images with Full path and the error is same! With the Relative path, it got images and the error still persists! Also python code is in the same path as the text files that it is reading and images are in the sub directory of python and text files path. It is like another folder called 'image' in the path of python and text files

Comment: maybe some relative pathes are OK but other not. You should check for every path separatelly if file exists or not.

Comment: if images are in subfolder `images` then relative path `Sbj47/Scn/Clr/rgb7` can't get it because it should be `images/Sbj47/Scn/Clr/rgb7`. You could use `os.getcwd() + "/ " + path` to convert relative pathes to full pathes and see if they are correct.

Comment: I changed the text files accordingly! As said before for every image that I get the error I am checking and it has been copied! I just don't know why this error keeps popping up!

Comment: then create new question. Put current code and full error message - you will more place to better describe problem. Now I have only mess in my mind because I don't know what code you use and what error you get. And I said before you can have mistake in different place of code.